# Edit file containing settings from within php

Tags: php

I have a file named config.php, it stores the variables that connect to a database, (Username, password etc) I want to be able to edit these settings from a html form(I have it setup)

I however cannot find out how to redefine these variables from the form, I send the form to the page updateDatabaseSettings.php but don't know how to then change them.

Your help in this would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have so far:

config.php

```
$DBUSER="root"; 
$DBPASS=""; 
$DBHOST="127.0.0.1"; 
$DBNAME="mydb";
```

updateDatabaseSettings.php

```
$newDBHOST = $_POST['dbhost'];
$newDBNAME = $_POST['dbname'];
$newDBUSER = $_POST['dbuser'];
$newDBPASS = $_POST['dbpass'];
```

Say the user input 192.168.1.2 for $newDBHOST I want that to replace the text in $DBHOST

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `updateDatabaseSettings.php` script would need to overwrite the contents of the `config.php` file.

A simple approach would be to construct a string containing all of the new content (including the `<?php  ?>` tags and all the variable declarations). You could then pass that string to `file_put_contents()` to overwrite the `config.php` file.

Remember to check your file permissions though. You need to allow the webserver to write to `config.php`, or it won't work.

Comment: Yes, it would replace everything in `config.php`. If you only want to replace part of the code then it's much more complicated. You'd have to read current contents, parse it to figure out which bits to modify, and then write the whole modified contents back out. It's probably not worth the hassle!

Comment: OK I do have other settings saved in that file but for the sake of simpleness I can split them into other files. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

you have many choices so it is hard to say but I would create two instances of DB connection - one default and second variable connection. Default connection can take configuration info from config.php and you can always connect to default db and second instance will always take configuration info directly from POST and create new connection when POST request is called.

Also you can use global variables and just rewrite them when you need or change config.php file directly with PHP ([look fopen,fwrite,fclose,... functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)).

Answer (score -1):

I guess include config.php in updateDatabaseSettings.php and replace the values ? Or even set these variables as global ? Then I suppose you have to kill and init a new db connection. hard to answer, would need to know how your app is architectured.

Comment: Essentially everypage that needs access to the database will include config.php.

Comment: So what's the issue ? You can't set a new value for $DBHOST ?

Comment: Yeah I don't know how to, I guess I could use PHP's file write system but after much googleing I am still oblivious as to how it works.

Comment: Do you mean write the file ??

Comment: Yes, so that `updateDatabaseSettings.php` would write the new settings to `config.php`

Comment: check out file_put_contents in php